# Updating Multiple Users in Active Directory - Problems with Country and Manager Attributes

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that will take user data from an SQL database and apply changes to the active directory if there is a discrepancy between the two. I am new to PowerShell as of September, and have been learning throughout this project.

Everything works fine, except for writing the updated Country and Manager changes to the AD. Here is the Set-ADUser portion.

```
Set-ADUser $row.SamAccountName -GivenName ($row.firstName) -Surname ($row.lastName) -Initials ($row.initials) -City ($row.city) -Company ($row.company) <#-Country ($row.country)#> -Department ($row.department) -DisplayName ($row.displayName) -Fax ($row.fax) <#-Manager ($row.manager)#> 
-MobilePhone ($row.mobile) -Office $row.office -PostalCode ($row.postalCode) -State ($row.province) -StreetAddress ($row.streetAddress) -OfficePhone ($row.telephoneNumber) -Replace @{ipPhone=$ipphone} -Title ($row.title) -HomePage ($row.website)
```

Aside from reconfiguring the ipPhone attribute, everything else is the same format. As you can see, this is my first post. Creating this account was my last resort. I have searched online for a solution for both, and I have also tried these solutions, but no dice.

The Country and Manager attributes are commented out because Set-ADUser changes will not write if either is uncommented. If you need anymore information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: i recommend you change from a long, long. long line of parameters to using a splat. `Get-Help about_Splatting` for more info on that. THEN, check to see what is actually in each value you are passing to the AD cmdlet by using `$SADU_Params` ... and confirm that what is there is what you need to be there. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you, I briefly read over splatting earlier on in the project, it does look cleaner for sure. I also managed to get the Country attribute working.

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// you may want to add your modified code to your Question so that others will be responding to your _current_ code base.